# Application Installation failed even having more space in memory

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem in my application where sometime it installs and runs but sometime it Shows INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE and removes my existing apk.
I tried by unchecking instant Run but still same problem.I have enough of space in my device but still gives the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVWkg.png)

Comment: try restarting your adb.

Answer (score 0):

1.remove old app installed in device and try agin
2.restart android studio and try agin

Answer (score 0):

Check mobile setting also

> -in Developer Mode check install via USB is true.

Or In your AndroidManifest.xml file add android:installLocation="preferExternal" within your manifest tag(external SD card)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.packagename.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

Comment: you can send all logcat